# Facebook app can't set bundle id for native iOS authentication

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am attempting to set up facebook authentication in a native iOS app using the Facebook SDK 3.0. This is the first facebook app I've set up myself.

I created my app on facebook and I am trying to set the Bundle ID in the "Native iOS App" section of the app basic settings on facebook. I enter my bundle id, which is in the format "com.mydomain.myappname", but no matter what I enter, when I save the changes, the Bundle ID is not stored.

Is there a step I am missing before I can set the Bundle ID?

The app is not in the app store yet, so I have not set the App Store IDs (my understanding is that these are not necessary?). I have set my app id in the plist for my iOS app

```
{FacebookAppID => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}
```

as well as the url scheme

```
{CFBundleURLSchemes => ["fbXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"]}
```

When I attempt to log in, I get the following error, which pretty clearly states that the bundle id is not set or doesn't match my iOS app bundle id:

> FBConditionalLog: System authorization failed:'The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: remote_app_id does not match stored id '. This may be caused by a mismatch between the bundle identifier and your app configuration on the server at developers.facebook.com/apps.

Comment: What are you entering for iPhone/iPad App Store ID. 
Please enter 0 and save the app details. Also provide screenshot for what error you're getting.

Comment: I was leaving the App Store IDs blank. I just tried again with your suggestion of entering 0 for the App Store IDs and my bundle ID saved correctly. Then tried again, leaving the App IDs blank to see if that was the actual problem, and it worked just fine. Perhaps it was a temporary issue with facebook's site.

Comment: I too hit this issue. In my case my AppStore ID in the FB App Dashboard was 123456.  The fix was: Set it to 0, test (still failed), then set it back to 123456. And then the error cleared. Seems that some magic happens when updating the appstore ID in the FB App Dashboard.

Comment: This is how I fixed this issue: [How to set the Bundle ID](http://cl.ly/image/2F060i3D0f10) A picture is worth a thousand words. ;-)

Comment: Also, the working solution to this issue was to set the App Store ID to 0 when setting the bundle ID, as Shireesh Asthana suggested.